# Angular 17 does not update view using setInterval with NG0500 error in console

Tags: angular, view, timer, setinterval, countdown

I am building a countdown timer component and trying to display updated 'seconds' value within every second, but I do not see any update on UI

When I do not use outside zone attitude, then page is just blank and loading infinitely.

.ts file

```
import { Component, ElementRef, NgZone, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-countdown',
  templateUrl: './countdown.component.html',
  styleUrl: './countdown.component.css'
})

export class CountdownComponent implements OnInit {

  static initialized: boolean = false;

  weddingDate: Date = new Date('2024-08-17T15:00:00');

  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}
  @ViewChild('seconds') seconds: ElementRef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(!CountdownComponent.initialized) {
      this.countdown(this.zone);
      CountdownComponent.initialized = true;
    }
  }

  countdown(zone: NgZone) {
    zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setInterval(() => { 
        this.seconds.nativeElement.innerHTML = (this.weddingDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
        console.log(this.seconds.nativeElement.innerHTML);
      }, 1000);
    })
  }
}
```

html file

```
<div #seconds> </div>
```

Comment: Your code is working for me

Comment: Well, so what could be the issue then? Maybe something in config?

Comment: I simplified your code, take a look a this https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jqjspj?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Make sure you have `import 'zone.js';` somewhere within your application. Removing it from the example I provided causes the same issue.

Comment: Thank you, but it is still not working in my app. I used exact same code you provided within every import.

Comment: I am guessing that this isn't related to your component then. You could try to delete `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`, and `.angular` then `npm install` again. Otherwise, I am out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Even this did not work, but thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: Do you use server side rendering (SSR)?

Comment: @Shlang I dont know to be honest. But in browser console I have error regarding hydration NG0500

Comment: @MisoDrotar could you update your question with this information as this is an important debugging detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NG0500](https://angular.dev/errors/NG0500) error means your project uses [Server Side Rendering (SSR)](https://angular.dev/guide/ssr). It means your application runs everything on the server first waits for asynchronous tasks to complete and then sends it to the client where the application continues to execute.

Running `setInterval` prevents the server from completing rendering as there is always an asynchronous task to execute. That is why wrapping it into `zone.runOutsideAngular` makes the difference, as Angular does not watch for it anymore, but this wrapping also makes these changes invisible for Change Detection on the client side which is why the counter is not updating there.

If you want to use SSR and make your code work, you can add a check for the platform, and start the counter only on the client:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-countdown',
  standalone: true,
  template: `<div>{{ secondsLeft }}</div>`,
})
export class CountdownComponent {

  weddingDate: Date = new Date('2024-08-17T15:00:00');
  secondsLeft: number;

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platform: Object) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!isPlatformServer(this.platform)) {
      this.countdown();
    }
  }

  countdown() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.secondsLeft = (this.weddingDate.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000;
    }, 1000);
  }

}
```

Please note that I also removed updating element's `innerHTML` as this is a bad practice in Angular in general, and causes [NG0500](https://angular.dev/errors/NG0500) error. It is always better to use bindings and avoid direct DOM manipulations.

---

I would strongly advise you not to use SSR if you don't fully understand how it affects your application. The simplest way to disable it is to change `angular.json` file by removing the following lines in `architect > build > options` section:

```json
"prerender": false,
"ssr": {
  "entry": "server.ts"
}
```

It disables SSR and you may want to remove some files related to SSR (they have `server` as a file name suffix).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, removing lines from angular.json worked, but the solution with isPlatformServer did not. Thanks a lot :)